# String splitting in python on basis of comma at one place and ignore comma at one place

Tags: python

I want to split the string
`"3,{1,2},107.516"` as  `["3" , "{1,2}","107.516"]` in python but when i separate on basis of comma it do separate `{1,2}` as `"{1" , "2}"`  which i don't want.

Can you please help me on what should I do to make it work?

Comment: Do you need to split this exact string?  Or can the string change?

Comment: string can change but format would be same like above. Numbers may change

Comment: Is it always exactly three numbers, with `{}` in the middle number?  Or can that change also?

Comment: yes these 3 elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions for that.

```
import re 

string = "3,{1,2},107.516"
r = re.compile('(\d),(\{[0-9,]+\}),([0-9.]+)')
print(r.match(string).groups())
```